# Cannot asynchronously open files inside class constructor

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm pretty new to C#. I'm trying to open a pair of CSV text files using the StorageFile class, but I need to do it inside a class constructor (which cannot be async):

```
private async Task SetupFileAccess()
{
    MainCarDataStorageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///leaf.csv"));
    var MainCarDataInputStream = await MainCarDataStorageFile.OpenReadAsync();
    var MainCarDataClassicStream = MainCarDataInputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    MainCarDataStream = new StreamReader(MainCarDataClassicStream);

    await MainCarDataStream.ReadLineAsync(); //clear header line from csv

    LookupTableStorageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Full_Charge_To_Empty.csv"));
    var LookupTableInputStream = await LookupTableStorageFile.OpenReadAsync();
    var LookupTableClassicStream = LookupTableInputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    LookupTableDataStream = new StreamReader(LookupTableClassicStream);

    await LookupTableDataStream.ReadLineAsync(); //clear header line from csv
}
```

Then I call `Wait()` on that function to block execution.

The problem is when I reach the second OpenReadAsync() function call to open a stream to the second file (Full_Charge_to_Empty.csv), the program just churns forever. No crash, no progress.

It seems I can only access the first file opened. If I comment out the first File access (leaf.csv), I am able to access the second file. If I switch their positions (leaf.csv is opened 2nd), I cannot open leaf.csv.

I feel like there must be something I don't understand about how these file accesses work...is it because my accessing of the first file (leaf.csv) is occupying a resource of some type? Appreciate the help!

Comment: How do you know it makes "no progress"? Presumably you have other code that depends on having read the files, and that code isn't shown here? The problem isn't that you already have one `StorageFile` open. There might be some issue with the file you're trying to open, or some other bug.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT, to debug I stepped through the code. It never exited out of the line "var LookupTableInputStream = await LookupTableStorageFile.OpenReadAsync();". Memory consumption just stayed flat forever, no apparent activity from what I was able to observe. I also have a task.Wait() call after this async function is called to prevent things from executing until it is done.

Comment: It seems I can only access the first file opened. If I comment out the first File access (leaf.csv), I am able to access the second file. If I switch their positions (leaf.csv is opened 2nd), I cannot open leaf.csv. I will edit the question to impart this info.

Comment: The problem is that you are doing a `Wait()` call -- that can cause deadlocks if you call it on the UI thread. What is causing you to `Wait()` rather than `await` the result?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I have the `Wait()` call in place in the function above this one (in this case class constructor) because as far as I can tell `await` only works in async functions, and I needed to make sure i had the file access working before continuing. Is that wrong? In any case, when I stepped through execution it never got to the `Wait()`...it seemed to get stuck at the second `OpenReadAsync()` call, regardless of which file I open first.

Comment: Yes, that's because the debugger is trying to be clever. You cannot reliably `Wait` on any async APIs, which means you can't rely on them completing in a constructor; if you really need the files to be ready by the time the object is instantiated, then consider a static async factory function that does all the I/O and then constructs the new object with the already-opened files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to force async functions to complete synchronously inside a constructor; that's not going to end well. The correct approach is to use an async factory method to front-load the work and then return a populated object. For example:

```
class Test
{
    // Make constructor private so no-one can create it
    private Test()
    { }

    // Simple string properties that can't be async
    public string Text1 { get; private set; }
    public string Text2 { get; private set; }

    // Async factory method that can do async things
    public static async Task<Test> CreateAsync()
    {
        var result = new Test();
        result.Text1 = await LoadFile("file1.txt");
        result.Text2 = await LoadFile("file2.txt");
        return result;
    }

    // Helper function
    static async Task<string> LoadFile(string filename)
    {
        var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(filename);
        var size = (await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).Size;
        var reader = new DataReader(await file.OpenReadAsync());
        reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)size);

        // assumes single-byte UTF codepoints, eg ASCII
        return reader.ReadString((uint)size);
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
var test = await Test.CreateAsync();
await new MessageDialog($"{test.Text1}{Environment.NewLine}{test.Text2}").ShowAsync();
return;
```

Comment: Ok thanks I think I see. This is probably a more basic question, but does that mean that we are always operating in async methods for interacting with files then?

Comment: The `Windows.Storage` APIs are async but if you use the .NET `System.IO` APIs you can choose sync or async versions (same with Win32).